# What VS debugger does so that increment operator performs faster than doing nothing?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, increment

Here is the self-explanatory code (performing an operation a billion times):

```
int k = 0;

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 1000; c++)
            k++;

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 1000; c++)
            ; // NO-OP

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The results are (at least on my computer) somewhere around (in milliseconds)

```
2168
2564
```

The second is always about half a second longer.

How is it possible that incrementing a variable a billion times runs longer than doing a no-op the same number of times?

**EDIT:** This happens only on DEBUG. Release does this correctly, the first one lasts longer, at least on my computer. As pointed in comments, someone experienced this problem even in RELEASE build. But what happens on DEBUG that creates this effect?

Comment: Did you run the code in Release build and without debugger attached?

Comment: @dtb I have edited my question. Indeed I did run it in DEBUG build, but still - even unoptimized, I'd expect it to run the increment longer than no-op. I wonder what is causing this, even in DEBUG.

Comment: Probably the debugger has more to do with an noop than an increment.
Do a debug build an run without debugger if you want to see if optimizations or the debugger itself are slowing the noop down.
Also check the msil to see what happens

Comment: @Aspelund that's even more interesting.

Comment: @Aspelund ctrl+F5? (ie without debugging) i get like 242,236

Comment: @Aspelund i get 1638, 1365 even with the debugger attached in release

Comment: Heres a fun one, I added a third case {} instead of ; as the noop, it takes a bit longer again (1525, 1785, 1816) and the same deal if I reorder them (ie order isnt the issue)

Comment: I believe {} and ; both end up as the same IL in this case.

Comment: yeah you would expect so but onmybox they are consistently different. Perhaps this is caused by debugger parsing

Comment: You can't trust the numbers when you have the debugger attached, specially not when you're doing the branches a lot faster than if you had an extra `add` in there.

Comment: I get the NOP loop faster, *even in Debug/Debug*. (x64, Win7, VS2012, Console App)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever only diff for me is win8

Comment: I averaged over 10 runs for the 3 scenarios (inc both noops) and got 236, 236, 243 in release with no debug

Comment: As always, note whether running under which runtime and what mode (x86, etc).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is as Azodious mentioned, you can't use debug mode to meassure the time because it will not be accurate.

With release mode on, I get the following numbers:

**Incrementing `k`**: 445

**NOP**: 402

There are 4 more `IL` instructions in the incrementing version:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     
IL_0005:  br.s        IL_003B
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  stloc.2     
IL_0009:  br.s        IL_0029
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  stloc.3     
IL_000D:  br.s        IL_0017
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0011:  add         
IL_0012:  stloc.0     
IL_0013:  ldloc.3     
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0015:  add         
IL_0016:  stloc.3     
IL_0017:  ldloc.3     
IL_0018:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_001D:  clt         
IL_001F:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0021:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0023:  brtrue.s    IL_000F
IL_0025:  ldloc.2     
IL_0026:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0027:  add         
IL_0028:  stloc.2     
IL_0029:  ldloc.2     
IL_002A:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_002F:  clt         
IL_0031:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0033:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0035:  brtrue.s    IL_000B
IL_0037:  ldloc.1     
IL_0038:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0039:  add         
IL_003A:  stloc.1     
IL_003B:  ldloc.1     
IL_003C:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_0041:  clt         
IL_0043:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0045:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0047:  brtrue.s    IL_0007
```

The `NOP`-verison has an equal amount of branches but one less `add`:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     
IL_0005:  br.s        IL_0037
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  stloc.2     
IL_0009:  br.s        IL_0025
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  stloc.3     
IL_000D:  br.s        IL_0013
IL_000F:  ldloc.3     
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0011:  add         
IL_0012:  stloc.3     
IL_0013:  ldloc.3     
IL_0014:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_0019:  clt         
IL_001B:  stloc.s     04 
IL_001D:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_001F:  brtrue.s    IL_000F
IL_0021:  ldloc.2     
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0023:  add         
IL_0024:  stloc.2     
IL_0025:  ldloc.2     
IL_0026:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_002B:  clt         
IL_002D:  stloc.s     04 
IL_002F:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0031:  brtrue.s    IL_000B
IL_0033:  ldloc.1     
IL_0034:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0035:  add         
IL_0036:  stloc.1     
IL_0037:  ldloc.1     
IL_0038:  ldc.i4      E8 03 00 00 
IL_003D:  clt         
IL_003F:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0041:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0043:  brtrue.s    IL_0007
```

These are compiled without optimization on because I want to see exactly what's going on.

The only difference between them in reality is:

```
IL_0012:  stloc.0     
IL_0013:  ldloc.3     
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0015:  add
```

**Simply put:** You're getting weird numbers because you're in debug mode.

Comment: totally agree that with debugger isnt a good way to measure performance, however im still really curious what the debugger is actually doing behind the scenes here to cause such substantial differences.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, I'm not sure, could only speculate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond testing the wrong code, a core mistake you made was assuming that you measured the cost of the increment operator.  You didn't, you measured the cost of the for() loops.  Which take a lot more cpu cycles than the increment.

An issue with a for() loop is that the cpu is forced to branch, jump back to the beginning of the loop.  Modern cpus do *not* like branching much, they are optimized to execute code sequentially.  A side effect of the *pipe-line*, a core architectural implementation detail designed to make a processor execute code fast.  A branch may force the processor to flush the pipe-line, throwing away a lot of work that turned out to be useless.  Lots of resources are allocated in a cpu design to reduce the cost of having to flush the pipe-line.  A core part is the *branch predictor*, it tries to guess up front which way a branch is going to go so it can fill the pipe-line with instructions that *may* be executed.  Guessing wrong is very expensive.  You don't have too much to fear from this if your for() loop is long enough.

Another issue with modern processors is that they are very sensitive to the alignment of the branch target.  In other words, the address of the instruction of the start of the loop.  If it is *mis-aligned*, not at an address that's divisible by 4 or 8 then the prefetch unit needs extra cycles to start decoding the correct instruction.  That's an implementation detail that the jitter needs to take care of, it may have to insert extra NOP instructions to get the instruction aligned.  The x86 jitter does not perform that optimization, the x64 jitter does.

An observable side-effect of alignment problems is that swapping the two pieces of code may affect your measurement.

Benchmarking code is a perilous adventure on modern cpus, the odds that you'll actually get in *real code* what you observed by profiling a synthetic version of the code are not good.  Differences of 15% or less are not statistically meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 3 times and outputs are:

> 3786
>
> 3252

---

> 3800
>
> 3256

---

> 3840
>
> 3255

So, if you are making a decision based on stats collected in debug mode, Don't.

Debug mode attached a lot of data to code that helps debugger during debugging.

Comment: I am aware of that. My question is actually asking - why does it happen? What exactly debugger does that makes the increment run faster than doing nothing?